# how to get value from localstorage of product details in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7, local-storage

How to get value from local storage of product weight and id in magento 2.

[image]

Comment: In which page you want to get?

Comment: View cart or shopping cart page – Rohan Hapani

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` class to get the quote and your cart items details.

---

**Using construct method :**

```
protected $_cart;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartModel,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_cart = $cartModel;
    ...
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $items = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo 'ID : '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Weight : '.$item->getWeight().'<br />';
    }
}
```

---

**using Object Manager :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection(); // get quote items collection

$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems(); // get array of all items what can be display directly

$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems(); // get quote items array

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID : '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Weight : '.$item->getWeight().'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment Rohan Hapani can see image i have uploaded i need to display product weight there above subtotal

Comment: are you able to get product weight on cart page  ?

Comment: By this code, it will be get value. But, he want to get in minicart.